# How can I do `dir *.mp3` in bash?

Tags: bash, find

On Windows I used to quickly run a `dir *.mp3` to find all files with an mp3 extension in the current directory. Is there a similarly quick way to do it with bash? The `ls` command seems to have a way to *ignore* a pattern, but not to show only the pattern. I can do `find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.mp3'` or `ls|grep -i '\.mp3$'` but neither of these flow out of my fingers in half a second or less)

Any quicker alternatives?

Comment: Note that it is the interpreter (bash) that does the wildcard substitution. Thus, `ls *.mp3` could result in a very long list (out of memory / command line too long), depending on how many files that match the globbing pattern. `bash` actually calls "`ls aGoodSong1.mp3 boringSong2.mp3 coolSong.mp3`" (if you have those 3 files). A workaround: `ls | grep -i '[.]mp3$'` (where ls lists all files and grep shows only the .mp3 files)

Comment: Just for fun, try `echo *.mp3`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried `ls *.mp3`?

Comment: Ooh, er, that's a bit strange. It works! I'm _sure_ that was the first thing I tried way back when. Is there any situation where this doesn't work? Thanks for responding:)

Comment: Yep, it won't show '*.MP3' files. You'll need to use `grep -i` in order to ignore the case

Comment: Or just do `ls *.mp3 *.MP3`

Comment: ... but: 
 ls *.[mM][pP]3 will.

Comment: I've been meaning to post about this for some time. Maybe it was a problem with `dir /s *.mp3`... anyways, thanks for an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Note that in *bash*, the star wildcard is resolved by the command line interpreter before the resulting array of strings is then passed to the command proper. On the *Windows (ex-DOS) command line*, the star wildcard is passed to the command 'as is', which then has to sadly deal with it. [See the Wikipedia globbing entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)

Try this to see how the wildcard behaves:

```
#!/bin/bash    
# Display all "positional parameters" (as they are called), passed to the script:    
# COUNT is the number of positional paramaters

COUNT=$#    
while [[ $COUNT -gt 0 ]]; do
   echo "'$1'"
   # pop positional argument 1 off the stack of positional arguments
   shift
   let COUNT=$COUNT-1
done
```